# starting event loop in subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am using `aiomultiprocess` to parallelize my program.

**Code:**

```
import asyncio
from aiomultiprocess import Pool


async def c(index):
    print("c" + index)


def main(index):
    print("b")
    asyncio.run(c(index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("a")
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(main, [i for i in range(2)])
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\------------------------------------------------\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    with Pool() as pool:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I have tried to use `multiprocessing` instead of `aiomultiprocess` but Error was even worse (to be more correct much longer). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you read the [usage section](https://github.com/omnilib/aiomultiprocess) of the README? You seem to be misusing the library (missing `async` keywords etc.)

Comment: yeah, I have tried that, but it isnt working because it isnt inside async function so i cant use async and await commands `SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function`

Answer (score 0):

This should work correctly:

```py
import asyncio
from aiomultiprocess import Pool

async def c(index):
    print("c" + str(index))

async def main(index):
    print("b")
    async with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(c, [i for i in range(2)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I think your problem arises from trying to create `Pool()` using normal `with`, rather than `async with`.